# Drop-down menu is behind revolution slider

Tags: css, menu, slider, z-index

my website [simfest](http://simfest.ro/) has an issue with the drop-down menu, it is behind the "revolution slider".

I searched for answers, and all lead to `z-index:xxx` - now I am confused, because I have 47 lines with `z-index:`

Any idea on what line of code I need to modify?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.submenu {
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

and `z-index: 0;` for the revolution slider container.

Comment: `z-index: 0;` added to revolution slider container, but I didn't find `.submenu {...`  Thank you for helping Nikola

Comment: Don't do it inline (in the html)...Find your style.css file...and define the styles there :) You are welcome